# How do i get the value using regex in jmeter

Tags: json, regex, jmeter, performance-testing

I need to correlate in jmeter for performance testing but am not able to fetch the required value.

```
    {
  "totalCount": 8,
  "data": [
    [
      "TEST_CLASS",
      "2020-05-18",
      "2020-05-18",
      9821844,
      "FY21 - WK 16",
      "FY21 - WK 16",
      null,
      "USER",
      "Name",
      "2020-05-11T10:45:14",
      283
    ],
    [
      "TEST_CLASS",
      "2020-05-18",
      "2020-05-18",
      9821842,
      "FY21 - WK 16",
      "FY21 - WK 16",
      null,
      "USER",
      "Name",
      "2020-05-11T10:30:45",
      283
    ],
    [
      "TEST_CLASS",
      "2020-05-18",
      "2020-05-18",
      9821848,
      "FY21 - WK 16",
      "FY21 - WK 16",
      null,
      "USER",
      "Name",
      "2020-05-11T11:11:21",
      283
    ],
    [
      "TEST_CLASS",
      "2020-05-18",
      "2020-05-18",
      9821843,
      "FY21 - WK 16",
      "FY21 - WK 16",
      null,
      "USER",
      "Name",
      "2020-05-11T10:39:03",
      283
    ],
    [
      "TEST_CLASS",
      "2020-05-18",
      "2020-05-18",
      9821846,
      "FY21 - WK 16",
      "FY21 - WK 16",
      null,
      "USER",
      "Name",
      "2020-05-11T10:54:55",
      283
    ],
    [
      "TEST_CLASS",
      "2020-05-18",
      "2020-05-18",
      9821849,
      "FY21 - WK 16",
      "FY21 - WK 16",
      null,
      "USER",
      "Name",
      "2020-05-11T12:35:45",
      283
    ],
    [
      "TEST_CLASS",
      "2020-05-18",
      "2020-05-18",
      9821845,
      "FY21 - WK 16",
      "FY21 - WK 16",
      null,
      "USER",
      "Name",
      "2020-05-11T10:50:57",
      283
    ],
    [
      "TEST_CLASS",
      "2020-05-18",
      "2020-05-18",
      9821847,
      "FY21 - WK 16",
      "FY21 - WK 16",
      null,
      "USER",
      "Name",
      "2020-05-11T11:05:58",
      283
    ]
  ],
  "additionalInfo": {
    "startDates": [
      "FY21 - WK 16"
    ],
    "createdByUsers": {
      "283": "USER Name"
    },
    "endDates": [
      "FY21 - WK 16"
    ]
  }
}
```

And every time i create record this `json` value will keep on increasing and need to fetch the last value  `9821847` used regex but its not helping me
All the info in `json` is correlated actually like `"2020-05-18"`, `"TEST_CLASS"`, `"FY21 - WK 16"`, `"USER"`, `"Name"`
only thing which is not corelated is the UTC timestamp `"2020-05-11T10:30:45",` Even this one am generating using `JSR223` post processor to use it in regex while creating record.

actual regex looks like :
`TEST_CLASS","${c3}","${c3}",(.*?),"${FY_WK}","${FY_WK}",null,"USER","Name","${utc_time}:`

if i remove the correlated values then it looks like 
`TEST_CLASS","2020-05-18","2020-05-18",(.*?),"FY21 - WK 16","FY21 - WK 16",null,"USER","Name","2020-05-11T11:05:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fetch all the values using [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) with below configurations

- Variable names: `MyVar`
- JSON Path expressions: `$.data.[*].[3]`
- Match Numbers: `-1`
- Default Values: `NOT_FOUND`

Then you can use `${__V(MyVar_${MyVar_matchNr})}` to get the last value.